# MVC Static files not doing its functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to include a jquery plugin in an MVC application via bundling css and js files.

But the functionality does not work.

I am aware about how to bundle the files with bundles.add(….)

What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
                              "~/js/rainbow.min.js",
                              "~/js/tiksluscarousel.js"));


                    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                              "~/css/animate.css",
                              "~/css/normalize.css",
                              "~/css/tiksluscarousel.css",
                              "~/css/github.css"));

        @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js") 

    Global asax:  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

Index.cshtml:
        <div id="fruits">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="~/images/fruits1.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/fruits2.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/fruits3.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/fruits4.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/fruits5.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/fruits6.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/fruits7.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="~/images/fruits8.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fruits").tiksluscarousel({width:640,height:480,nav:'thumbnails',current:1,type:'zoom'});
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: What is it you’re trying to do and what is it that’s not working?

Comment: It's a Carousel jquery plugin. The plugin doesn't get the functionality of image swapping

Comment: I have edited my question with the code. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the files to a bundle you'll need to reference the bundle in your headers, and be sure to register your bundles in your Global.asax file i.e.

Global file:

```
// Registers default bundle collection
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

You also need to split the bundles to register styles and scripts separately so in your headers you can run:

Layout Sheet:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundleLocation/cssBundleName")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundleLocation/scriptBundleName")
```

The final item (which is what this one is), the bundle names can't be the same as the folder locations of the bundles so where there is

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
"~/js/rainbow.min.js",
"~/js/tiksluscarousel.js"));


bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
"~/css/animate.css",
"~/css/normalize.css",
"~/css/tiksluscarousel.css",
"~/css/github.css"));
```

You'll just need to rename the ScriptBundles to something other than /js and /css

i.e

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jsScripts").Include(
"~/js/rainbow.min.js",
"~/js/tiksluscarousel.js"));


bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/cssStyles").Include(
"~/css/animate.css",
"~/css/normalize.css",
"~/css/tiksluscarousel.css",
"~/css/github.css"));
```

This is just a routing convention of MVC where it will be confused by the bundle name and attempt to link a non-existing folder

Comment: I have done exactly what you have mentioned but it doesn't work

Comment: When loading the page have you checked the console for any JS errors (if using chrome hit f12, then the console tab).

Also are both items not working, just the Js not working, or just the CSS not working? And finally, are the bundles located in the standard MVC location (App_Start/BundleConfig.cs)

Comment: wow. It says $ not defined...which means jquery is not getting loaded

Comment: ah k, so from there have you registered the /bundles/jquery bundle at all (mostly comes prebundled in new MVC projects, otherwise you may need to make your own)

Comment: Yep I have 2 bundles :  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
Why doesn't it load?

Comment: That should be fine, are those 2 added to your layout page before the two new bundles? Also have you checked the JS library to make sure your jquery script has been labelled in the same format (i.e. not missing any dashes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173025/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-rando).